# Is it possible to have one endpoint in an NServiceBus SOA use a different serializer from the rest?

Tags: .net, serialization, messaging, nservicebus

Somewhat related to: [Is it possible for an NServiceBus endpoint to Handle and Publish using different serializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13035894/38360)

We already have wide deployment of NServiceBus in our infrastructure and it is all configured using the `XmlSerializer`. However, a one-off situation has come up in which the `XmlSerializer` is not going to meet our requirements, so I'm considering `JsonSerializer` or `BinarySerializer`.

Changing every single endpoint in the entire infrastructure to use a different serializer would be highly disruptive and time-wasting in terms of deployments, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to introduce one new endpoint that uses a different serializer... or rather, it's easy to configure the endpoint *itself* to use an alternate serializer, but I'm not sure how I can get any other endpoint to *talk to it*.

Am I stuck with one serializer type used throughout the entire architecture if I'm using NServiceBus 3.x? I seem to remember reading once, I think on the NServiceBus message boards, that serialization could be defined at the endpoint level, but there weren't many details given and the person who wrote that answer may have been overlooking the obvious interop issue above.

I want the architecture to look something like this:

```
+---------+      +------------+ (pub/sub) +------------+
| Web App |----->| Endpoint A |<--------->| Endpoint B |<-------> ...
+---------+      +------------+           +------------+
     |               (XML)                     (XML)
     |
     |           +------------+
     +---------->| Endpoint C |
                 +------------+
                     (JSON)
```

The problem is, of course, that although I can obviously configure Endpoint C to use the `JsonSerializer` exclusively (and am OK with this), the "Web App" still needs to have its own (send-only) bus in order to talk to either Endpoint A or Endpoint C. And that bus has to be configured using *one* serializer. Since it already sends messages to a number of `XmlSerializer`-based endpoints, I can't just switch it to `JsonSerializer`. And there's no way that I've been able to find in the configuration or docs to direct NServiceBus to serialize some messages differently, either at the message level or at the endpoint level. I'm not even sure if the changes in NSB 4/5 are technically going to support this because they're all around how messages are *received*, not *sent*.

Is there a configuration method or setting somewhere that I'm missing that would allow me to do this? And if not, what other sensible options are there? Perhaps hosting two endpoints in the Web App? Or maybe a custom serializer that delegates to other serializers?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a transport level [message mutator](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/894155-nservicebus-message-mutators-sample) in the NSB pipeline.  It may be the case that the mutation happens too late in the processing, but it is worth a look.  Otherwise you'll need to implement a custom serializer as you mentioned to handle all the different formats.

Another thought would be to turn on the Gateway in all the endpoints.  This would get you down to HTTP on all endpoints and I'm hoping that would solve it.  Again, I have not confirmed this, just putting some ideas out there.

Comment: I actually made an attempt at the custom serializer today but got stuck on the *Deserialization* part of it, where all you have to go by is a `Stream`. Any idea how to work around that? I think NSB 4 uses headers, but I'm not sure how to get at those from within a serializer.

Comment: 3 uses headers as well, they should be in the Exstension field on the message.  It should contain the type of the message.

Comment: The `IMessageSerializer.Deserialize` interface only takes a `Stream` as a parameter; there doesn't appear to be any way to obtain headers or any transport message information at all. However, I determined that in my particular implementation, I only needed to *send* (serialize) in different formats, and it was okay to always use the `XmlMessageSerializer` for *receiving* messages because the new/fiddly endpoint is all fire-and-forget. So I got a bit lucky.

Comment: Oh, and I'm fairly certain the mutator option wouldn't have worked because the underlying problem is that `XmlMessageSerializer` *can't serialize* the messages. So the entire transport would fail before the mutator would even have a chance to kick in.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 5 of NServiceBus we've added some basic support for this scenario but more recently with version 6 it is now much more complete.

You can find more information about it here:

https://particular.net/blog/build-a-babel-fish-nservicebus